# Problems with parameter selection

Tags: c++, fltk

I am having trouble to pick one of these numbers in fltk.

```
    Fl_Input_Choice* OFILE = new Fl_Input_Choice(260, 240, 100, 20, "My Parameters");
    OFILE->add("1");
    OFILE->add("2");
    OFILE->add("3");
```

If I click over 1, the choice is 1, over 2, choice is 12, while it should be 2. Same is true if i click 2 or 3 after clicking 1. I will get 12 ot 123.

If I click over 1, then 2. It should print 2 not 12. How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Is you answer equivalent to this: read sequence is characters from stdio, and print them on console in same sequence sym by symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by declaring a string that read the char value.